# While Zooming and Pinching map , Google map is moving

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have referred all the below mentioned but nothing helped me. My requirement is if we double tab or zoom in or zoom out ,map and entered image should not move like Uber,Carrem.I am new to IOS. I have placed the code,Can anyone help me,

[Zoom in the center of the screen - Google Maps iOS SDK Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087475/zoom-in-the-center-of-the-screen-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift)
[Google Maps SDK iOS - prevent map from changing location on zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990873/google-maps-sdk-ios-prevent-map-from-changing-location-on-zoom)
[How to setCenter mapview with location in google maps sdk for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026923/how-to-setcenter-mapview-with-location-in-google-maps-sdk-for-ios)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface ViewController ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
//To hide the default gestures
self.mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom=NO;
//self.mapView.settings.zoomGestures=NO;
//self.mapView.settings.rotateGestures=NO;

//After loading page camera will point this.
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:24.840216
                                                        longitude:46.676199
                                                             zoom:14];
[self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton=TRUE;

//Make the image as center of the map

UIImageView *pin =[[UIImageView alloc]init];
pin.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40  );
pin.center = self.mapView.center;
pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"];
[self.view addSubview:pin];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:pin];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *doubleTab = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPan:)];
doubleTab.delegate=self;
//doubleTab.numberOfTapsRequired=2;
[self.mapView  addGestureRecognizer:doubleTab];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void) didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    NSLog(@"YES");
    self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = YES;
}
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
if (gestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches > 1)
{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer:NO");
    self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = NO;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer:YES");
    self.mapView.settings.scrollGestures = YES;
}
return true;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:1.285
                                                          longitude:103.848
                                                               zoom:12];
  GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  mapView.settings.scrollGestures = NO;
  mapView.settings.zoomGestures = NO;
  self.view = mapView;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response .. @iosdeveloperweb Can you pls tell me where we have to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the response .. @iosdeveloperweb.wordpress.com    Can you pls tell me where we have to do this? –